# What is the average minimum distance between two Sobol points?

Tags: random, monte-carlo

Having the first n points of a d-dimensional Sobol sequence, what is the average Euclidean distance from one arbitrarily point to its nearest neighbour?

Answer (score 0):

Good question - the minimum distance is at least 0.5 * sqrt(d) / n, see "Quasi-random points keep their distance" on http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382